# Installation of ncurses-bin fails with "unable to make backup symlink for './usr/bin/infotocap': No such file or directory"

Tags: apt, package-management, 15.10, dpkg, 16.04

For some unknown reason the package dependencies on my Ubuntu 15.10 got messed up. `sudo apt-get -f install` fails because the installation of `ncurses-bin` fails with

```
unable to make backup symlink for './usr/bin/infotocap': No such file or directory
```

As a silly workaround I tried create an empty file and directory `intotocap` relative to `.` and changing the current directory, but `/`, `/root`, `/tmp` and `$HOME` didn't work.

I unpackaged the `.deb` archive and grepped for `intotocap`, but it doesn't occur which leaves me with a lot of confusion.

`No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system` is printed to console which doesn't make sense to me because trying to backup an inexisting directory is an installation script, i.e. no local, error for me.

The complete output:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ifupdown libncurses5 libncurses5:i386 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5 libpam-systemd libplymouth4 libsmartcols1 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5-dbg
  libudev-dev libudev1 libudev1:i386 mdadm ncurses-bin plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text systemd systemd-dbg udev util-linux
Suggested packages:
  rdnssd ncurses-doc desktop-base plymouth-themes systemd-ui systemd-container util-linux-locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ifupdown libncurses5 libncurses5:i386 libncurses5-dev libncursesw5 libpam-systemd libplymouth4 libsmartcols1 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5-dbg
  libudev-dev libudev1 libudev1:i386 mdadm ncurses-bin plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text systemd systemd-dbg udev util-linux
25 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3984 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38,0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2.551 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [J/n] j
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 971243 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ncurses-bin_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ncurses-bin (6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1) over (5.9+20150516-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ncurses-bin_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup symlink for './usr/bin/infotocap': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ncurses-bin_6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I experienced with error on 15.10 for months (also reported at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncurses/+bug/1523196), but it never kept me from installing packages. No I did a `sudo do-release-upgrade --devel-release` since I wanted to test some features of 16.04. The upgrade in VirtualBox went without problem, so that I'm sure that this is not a matter of using packages of the unreleased 16.04.

I can't uninstall `ncurses-bin` because it's an essential package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by `/usr/bin/infotocap` being a symlink to itself (which doesn't make sense for me). I removed the symlink and invoked `sudo apt-get -f install` again. I suggested better feedback of `dpkg` at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1552957.

Answer (score 0):

I found this having a similar error.

```
Preparing to unpack .../binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.37.90.20220123-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu (2.37.90.20220123-2) over (2.37-10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.37.90.20220123-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to make backup symlink for './usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gold': No such file or directory
```

Also resolved as mentioned above by uninstalling "binutils" and dependant packages until the upgrade started to work again.
Running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` did not resolve the problem.